# Cannot import virtual appliance into libvirt/kvm

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, kvm, libvirt, ovirt

Im currently pulling my hair out over this. Im new to KVM and i am simply trying to import a security applicance in qcow2 format. The issue is I am not understanding the process to do so. I am well versed in vmaware bt im not understanding what I need to do here.

Can't connect to Vm hosts with virt-manager because sasl is failing. through ovirt web portal the import process is convoluted and I'm missing what I need to do. Please help.

Comment: Look at the manual for `qemu-img` cmdline, `man qemu-img` on a Linux box, assuming that's what you are using. `qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O qcow2 input.vmdk output.qcow2`

Comment: thank you for the comment but its the opposite situation, i already have a qcow2 formatted file. LAso the primary issue here is that I am not understanding how the uri format for the image import. must i convert the vm to import?